# How to rename dataframes inside a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rename

I've got a list of dataframes. The list object contains 85 dataframes, their names are simply numbers from 1 to 85.

I want to rename each one of them with dates, starting from 2021/8/8 to 2021/10/31 (85 days, of course).

What I tried:

```
df_names <-seq(from = as.Date("2021-08-08"), to = as.Date("2021-10-31"), by="day")
df_list <-lapply(dflist, setNames, new.names= df_names)
```

And also:

```
df_names <-seq(from = as.Date("2021-08-08"), to = as.Date("2021-10-31"), by="day")
df_list[[1:n]] <- df_names
```

None of them worked. How can I solve it?

This is the error I got in the first case:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :    unused argument

Comment: Do you want to name the each dataframe within a list `names(df_list) <- df_names`? or Do you want to rename the column names within each dataframe?

Comment: No I do not want to rename the columns, I just want to rename the names of the dataframes inside the list.

Comment: Great, then linked post should have the correct answer.